# Cannot get unique values in card array

Tags: javascript

I am new to programming and javascript and i have a question ive been struggling with for a bit now. Im trying to build a card game and have a card object which returns a card representation of the format (card #,suit eg. 5,Hearts). I deal a card at the start of the program and validate that the card dealt is unique (ie not been used already). I have the following structure:

```
var usedCards= [];

function dealCards() {
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  { 
    var card = createUniqueCard();
    usedCards.push(card.cardRepresentation);
  }
}

function createUniqueCard() {
  do {
    var newCard = new Card();
  }
  while (usedCards.indexOf(newCard.cardRepresentation) != -1);

  return newCard;
}
```

This still returns me duplicate cards in my usedCards array. Can anyone point out my logic error?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `newCard.cardRepresentation` is an object then `.indexOf()` will never find a match because two object references are considered equal only if they refer to the same *instance* - you keep creating new instances with `new Card()`.

If you can have `newCard.cardRepresentation` as a string it should work. Or if you write your own function to replace `.indexOf()`, where your function knows how to compare two `.cardRepresentation` objects...

I think a better solution is to begin by generating all possible cards, putting them in an array, and then your deal function could randomly select from that array.

Comment: um the replacing .indexOf() sounds good. Can you point me to where i can learn to do that?

Comment: I think you're better off generating all possible cards in advance and then randomly selecting from them - if you store references to those cards rather than generating new ones you can compare them or use `.indexOf()` - but anyway if you'd tell me what the structure of your `Card` and `cardRepresentation` objects is I could update my question with a simple example.